# How to selectively enable autocorrect based on language?

Tags: ios, autocorrect

My (bilingual) mom just recently bought an iPad.  When typing in Korean, her native language, she became irritated by the autocorrect feature -- it would often suggest incorrect spelling corrections, forcing her to pause typing to press the 'x' button to cancel it.  However, because she's not proficient in English, she found the autocorrect feature very useful when typing in English.

We found a way to completely disable autocorrect, but couldn't find a way to selectively enable it based on the keyboard language.  Is there a way to do this, or something similar?  Alternatively, is there a way to configure the settings so that the autocorrect suggestions do not automatically take effect after hitting the spacebar?

(If it matters, she has an iPad 3 (I think.  I'm pretty new to Apple too))

Comment: Please accept the answer that solved your problem. If you did something else that is not in the answers yet, post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

I just found a great solution for this problem: Install [Gboard](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gboard-search.-gifs.-emojis/id1091700242?mt=8) which is Google board and it's English. It has autocorrect and also Swype which is great.

Edit your keywords in settings/ general/keyboards
Delete the English keyboard
Add Gboard
Disable auto correct
Result: auto correction for English and English only.

Gboard also has emoji search

Answer (score 2):

There is no possibility to turn on autocorrect for one language on the keyboard but not on another. There is the setting "Check spelling that only underlines 'incorrect' words, but does not change it. I like to use that feature, as I am also bilingual. When that feature is on, you can first type your text and then tap the underlines one by one and then pick the suggestion you want.

If you want to jailbreak your iPad, then you could install a tweak called 'ManualCorrect' that only changes the word to the suggestion when you tap it.

Source: own experience and http://iphonemonsta.com/manualcorrect-autocorrect-fix-iphone-ios-cydia